# Upload a file to a cloud storage without exposing an API token

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload, cloud, storage

To upload a file from a client to a cloud storage we need an API token.

At the same time, an API token should be keeped privately.

As far as I understand, the easiest implementation would be:

1. To upload a file locally to the application server
2. From the application server to upload a file already to a cloud storage using an API.

The biggest issue of this approach is an extra traffic and overloading of the application server, which I really want to avoid.

Is there any way to upload a file directly to a cloud without exposing an API token on a client side? Perhaps, there is some redirect or forward command, which allows to add an API token to the initial request and then to redirect a request with a file to a cloud, or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cloud storage offers an API that allow streaming of the file, for example, in a `PUT`-request, you can use [`busboy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) to upload a file that is sent by an HTML `<form>`. The following code converts the incoming stream of type `multipart/form` (which comes from the browser) into an outgoing stream of the file's MIME-type (which goes to the cloud storage API):

```js
app.post("/uploadform", function(req, res) {
  req.pipe(busboy({headers: req.headers})
    .on("file", function(name, file, info) {
      file.pipe(https.request("<cloud storage endpoint>", {
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "<API token>",
          "Content-Type": info.mimeType
        },
        method: "PUT"
      }).on("response", function(r) {
        res.send("Successfully uploaded");
      }));
  }));
});
```

The advantage of this approach is that the file is not stored on the application server. It only passes through the application server's memory chunk by chunk.