# JavaScript `File.slice()` vs `File.stream().getReader().read()` - benefits of using streams for chunked reading?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript there are currently 2 alternatives for streaming a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) as blocks of [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array):

1. **`slice()`**: `File.`[`slice( start, end )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/slice)

   This gives a sub-[`Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), which can then be read via [`new FileReader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)`.`[`readAsArrayBuffer( blob )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer); the `ArrayBuffer` can be cast to `Uint8Array`.
2. **`stream()`**: `File.`[`stream()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/stream)`.`[`getReader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader)`.`[`read()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader/read)

   This goes via [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) -> [`ReadableStreamDefaultReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader), and `read()`'s `.value` gives the `Uint8Array`.

(The motivation for this "chunked" reading is usually processing large `File`s which the user Drag-and-Dropped into the browser, without reading them into memory all at once.)

Some differences I found:

- `slice()` is older, `stream()` is newer.
- `slice()` allows specifying a buffer size, while `stream()` is [fixed to 64 KiB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75438515/how-can-i-read-chunks-from-stream-in-javascript/75438959#75438959) in current browsers.

The older `slice()` seems more flexible on all axes, providing random access (permitting easy parallel processing) and allowing custom buffer sizes (libraries such as [`hash-wasm` are much faster](https://github.com/Daninet/hash-wasm/tree/bd3a205ca5603fc80adf71d0966fc72e8d4fa0ef#benchmark) on larger buffers).

### Question

**Are there any benefits to using `stream()` for this type of chunked `File` reading?**

Perhaps `stream()` can implement some optimisations, such as better read-ahead or better support/performance when loading data from a local network mount? Evidence would be appreciated.

Comment: What processing exactly do you want to do?

Comment: @Bergi The type of processing does not really matter for this question. In-browser hashing, searching in files, compression, chunked uploading, are all applications I'm interested in. But the question is on chunked bytes reading with browser APIs, which is a prerequisite for all of those.

Comment: I'd guess that libraries for some of those would take a `ReadableStream` as the input, so they can be used on any streamable source not just blobs. For them, the benefit would just be the generally fitting API interface. But if you're implementing something for yourself, and only need to read files, it probably doesn't matter.